# Concept for archiving huge database

Tags: mysql, database

I need a concept how I can archive all data in D-Pool which is older than one year.
At the moment we have more than 3 million records in the D-Pool.
Because of this huge data foundation searches and filters over the database takes quite too long, because most searches are done over the whole D-Pool data, but in most cases I am only interested in current data.
So I want to archive regularly all data from D-pool which is not needed for current work and evaluations.
But for some functions it should be possible furthermore to do a search over the whole D-pool, the current and the old data.

Could you tell me some ideas for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This describes the typical data warehousing solution.  Most owners of large datasets that change daily have a transactional database and a historical or reporting database.  The historical or reporting database allows users to mine for insight against everything - except the data added since the last extract.  That's usually sufficient.